# howto globally substitute nil values with a specific character (e.g. "-") in rails views

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I guess it's a simple question, but how can I replace nil values in generell in my views.
I want to avoid having something like

```
<% unless value == nil %>
  <%= value %> Ohm
<% else %>
  <p>-</p>
<% end %>
```

Where is the best place to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally put little formatters like this in a helper:

```
module ResistorsHelper
  def format_resistance(resistance)
    resistance.nil? ? content_tag(:p, '-') : "#{resistance} Ohm"
  end
end
```